# c++ selection sort with separate minimum index function

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, minimum, selection-sort

Hi I'm doing a problem for my c++ class where we are to create a generic selection sort function for all types with separate function that finds minimum index. I tried to modify selection sort function that uses two for loops by separating the two for loops into two separate functions.
I tried different ways to approach this problem but I just don't get what I am doing wrong. Please help.

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<time.h>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
unsigned min_index(const vector<T> &vals, unsigned index){
    auto min = index;
    for(auto i = index +1; i != vals.end();i++){
        if(*i < *min)
            min = i;
    }
    return min;
}

template <typename T>
void selection_sort(vector<T> &vals){
    for(auto i=vals.begin(); i!=vals.end(); i++){
        auto min = min_index(vals, i);
        swap(*i, *min);
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now, the biggest problem is the code won't compile. `if(*i < *min)` makes no sense. `i` and `min` are both just `unsigned`. Therefore, both `*i` and `*min` are nonsense. Fixing that, `auto min = min_index(vals, i);` in the `selection_sort` function is further nonsense, since `i` in that context is an iterator, but the function is expecting an `unsigned` for the `index` parameter. In short, this code looks like you tried to mash an iterator-based selection sort from one place, to a positional index-based min-index implementation from another place. Pick one method and stick with it.

Comment: why do you think something is wrong? Please explain the issue. Try to create a [mcve] including example input, output and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to develop a positional-index based `min_index` (which is dreadfully broken itself), then use it within an iterator-based selection sort.

```
template <typename T>
unsigned min_index(const vector<T> &vals, unsigned index)
{
    auto min = index; // min is 'unsigned' like 'index'

    // this loop is nonsense.
    //  'i' is unsigned (because 'index' is unsigned)
    //  'vals.end()' is an iterator, not an unsigned, therefore...
    //  'i != vals.end()` is nonsense.
    //  'min' is also unsigned, therefore...
    //  both *i and *min are nonsense.
    for(auto i = index +1; i != vals.end();i++)
    { 
        if(*i < *min)
            min = i;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Later on, in your selection-sort...

```
template <typename T>
void selection_sort(vector<T> &vals){
    // here 'i' is an iterator
    for(auto i=vals.begin(); i!=vals.end(); i++)
    {
        // here you're trying to pass an iterator to a function
        // expecting an unsigned. 
        auto min = min_index(vals, i);

        // and the above function is returning an unsigned
        // therefore *min is nonsense.
        swap(*i, *min);
    }
}
```

In short, *neither* of those functions can possibly compile, much less work.

---

You need to choose one or the other and stick with it. This is C++, so the easiest to implement is likely an iterator version. As a bonus, it also ends up being the most generic (there are iterators literally *everywhere* in modern C++). For example, the `min_index`, rewritten as `min_iter`, could look like this:

```
template<class Iter>
Iter min_iter(Iter beg, Iter end)
{
    auto min = beg;
    for (; beg != end; ++beg)
    {
        if (*beg < *min)
            min = beg;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Now you can use *that* in an iterator-based selection-sort as well:

```
template <class Iter>
void selection_sort(Iter beg, Iter end)
{
    for (; beg != end; ++beg)
        std::iter_swap(beg, min_iter(beg, end));
}
```

And finally, you can front this with a generic sequence abstraction by utilizing the general `std::begin` and `std::end` functions from the standard library:

```
template<class Seq>
void selection_sort(Seq& seq)
{
    selection_sort(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq));
}
```

Now you can pass a vector, a deque, an array, etc. Pretty much any sequence container instance will work, so long as the underlying element type supports `operator <` either natively or by overload.

---

**Position Based**

A similar solution specific to your container type (a vector) and ordinal position rather than iterators would be something like this:

```
template <typename T>
unsigned min_index(const std::vector<T> &vals, unsigned index)
{
    unsigned min = index;
    for (unsigned i = index + 1; i < vals.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vals[i] < vals[min])
            min = i;
    }
    return min;
}

template <typename T>
void selection_sort(std::vector<T> &vals)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++)
        std::swap(vals[i], vals[min_index(vals, i)]);
}
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you for explaining it. But how would you implement it using position-index? min_index(const vector<T> &vals, unsigned index) and selection_sort(vector<T> &vals) were given so I can't change it.

Comment: @HauresXI you'd use `vals[i]` instead of the non-existent `*i`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have right now but I'm getting unknown errors on the grading site (works well on my compiler). I got unknown errors when using int vectors and double vectors and got the value wrong when using string vector. Anyone see any problem I should fix?

For string:

Expected: b edmb ghnh irlwv ko kuc ngpo ogrme qgls qlk rgj ryy sos uchfm uwk wus x

Actual: b edmb ghnh irlwv ko qlk kuc ngpo ogrme qgls rgj ryy sos uchfm uwk x wus

```
template <typename T>
unsigned min_index(const vector<T> &vals, unsigned index){
    T min = vals[index];
    unsigned mindex;
    for(unsigned i = index +1; i < vals.size();i++){
        if(vals[i] < min){
            min = vals[i];
            mindex=i;
        }
    }
    
    return mindex;
}

template <typename T>
void selection_sort(vector<T> &vals){
    for(unsigned i=0; i < vals.size();  i++){
        unsigned min = min_index(vals, i);
        swap(vals[i],vals[min]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have undefined behaviour if the minimum element is the first you consider, i.e. if `mindex` remains uninitialised, which is always the case in the final call. Don't bother with `min` and `mindex`, have the condition `if(vals[i] < vals[index]) { index = i; }` and `return index;`

Comment: Thank you so much I finally got the full score for this! Thank you and I hope you have an excellent day (or night depending on where you live)!!!!